# Icons are not showing on application bar on my fluxbox

Tags: fluxbox

Some applications stopped showing their icons on the toolbar. Google Chrome shows nothing, Eclipse shows a red Square, brackets show nothing.
Chrome and Brackets were installed using dpkg, eclipse was just unpacked.
Other applications such as libreoffice, skype and terminator show their icons just fine. How can I diagnose better what is going on?

Comment: Did you recently change your system configuration? Install a new version of anything? Change your fluxbox theme?

Comment: Some applications i keep updated, like chrome and brackets. Eclipse shows a red square since first time. Theme i use the same for months